# Large file uploads over HTTP (How does MediaFire do it?)

Tags: flash, file-upload

Looking to make an in-house clone of MegaUpload/MediaFire. Using POST isn't going to cut it, I want files like 200MB.

I see that MegaUpload uses Flash, but I want to avoid flash because Apple doesn't seem keen on playing nice any time soon.

MediaFire uses something with the HTML5 File API, but how are they doing the actual upload? I can't find any Flash Objects on the page. Anyone know how they're doing it, or how I can do 200MB file uploads without flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use flash. Click the big green box where it says to drag/drop files to upload. The dialog that shows up contains a flash object.